# Convert a recursive variadic template function into iterative

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Say I have the following stuct

```
#include <functional>

template <typename ...T>
struct Unpack;

// specialization case for float
template <typename ...Tail>
struct Unpack<float, Tail...>
{
    static void unpack(std::function<void(float, Tail...)> f, uint8_t *dataOffset)
    {
        float val;
        memcpy(&val, dataOffset, sizeof(float));

        auto g = [&](Tail&& ...args)
        {
            f(val, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
        };

        Unpack<Tail...>::unpack(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, dataOffset + sizeof(float));
    }
};

// base recursive case
template <typename Head, typename ... Tail>
struct Unpack<Head, Tail...>
{
    static void unpack(std::function<void(Head, Tail...)> f, uint8_t *dataOffset)
    {
        Head val;
        memcpy(&val, dataOffset, sizeof(Head));

        auto g = [&](Tail&& ...args)
        {
            f(val, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
        };

        Unpack<Tail...>::unpack(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, dataOffset + sizeof(Head));
    }
};

// end of recursion
template <>
struct Unpack<>
{
    static void unpack(std::function<void()> f, uint8_t *)
    {
        f(); // call the function
    }
};
```

All it does is takes a `std::function` and a byte-array, and chunks off the byte-array, applying those chunks as function's arguments, recursively, until all arguments are applied, and then call the function.

The issue I'm having with this is that it generates quite a lot of templates. This is especially noticeable when used extensively in debug mode -- it causes the binary to grow very fast.

Given the following use case

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


void foo1(uint8_t a, int8_t b, uint16_t c, int16_t d, uint32_t e, int32_t f, uint64_t g, int64_t h, float i, double j)
{
    cout << a << "; " << b << "; " << c << "; " << d << "; " << e << "; " << f << "; " << g << "; " << h << "; " << i << "; " << j << endl;
}

void foo2(uint8_t a, int8_t b, uint16_t c, int16_t d, uint32_t e, int32_t f, int64_t g, uint64_t h, float i, double j)
{
    cout << a << "; " << b << "; " << c << "; " << d << "; " << e << "; " << f << "; " << g << "; " << h << "; " << i << "; " << j << endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t *buff = new uint8_t[512];
    uint8_t *offset = buff;

    uint8_t a = 1;
    int8_t b = 2;
    uint16_t c = 3;
    int16_t d = 4;
    uint32_t e = 5;
    int32_t f = 6;
    uint64_t g = 7;
    int64_t h = 8;
    float i = 9.123456789;
    double j = 10.123456789;

    memcpy(offset, &a, sizeof(a));
    offset += sizeof(a);
    memcpy(offset, &b, sizeof(b));
    offset += sizeof(b);
    memcpy(offset, &c, sizeof(c));
    offset += sizeof(c);
    memcpy(offset, &d, sizeof(d));
    offset += sizeof(d);
    memcpy(offset, &e, sizeof(e));
    offset += sizeof(e);
    memcpy(offset, &f, sizeof(f));
    offset += sizeof(f);
    memcpy(offset, &g, sizeof(g));
    offset += sizeof(g);
    memcpy(offset, &h, sizeof(h));
    offset += sizeof(h);
    memcpy(offset, &i, sizeof(i));
    offset += sizeof(i);
    memcpy(offset, &j, sizeof(j));

    std::function<void (uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t, uint32_t, int32_t, uint64_t, int64_t, float, double)> ffoo1 = foo1;
    Unpack<uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t, uint32_t, int32_t, uint64_t, int64_t, float, double>::unpack(ffoo1, buff);

    // uint64_t and in64_t are switched
    //std::function<void (uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t, uint32_t, int32_t, int64_t, uint64_t, float, double)> ffoo2 = foo2;
    //Unpack<uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t, uint32_t, int32_t, int64_t, uint64_t, float, double>::unpack(ffoo2, buff);

    return 0;
}
```

the debug binary I get with the two lines being commented is 264.4 KiB, but when I uncomment the two lines it becomes 447.7 KiB, 70% bigger than the original.

Same with release mode: 37.5 KiB vs. 59.0 KiB, 60% bigger than the original.

It makes sense to replace the recursion with iteration, something like an initializer list applied to the variadic `Unpack<...>:unpack()`, so that C++ would generate only a template per a type.

The code above compiles just fine, if you want to play with it a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote some crazy thing with templates and index sequences and tuples fully constrained with concepts from [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), and it was fine. Then it occurred to me it would be easier for the compiler to optimize if you unpack the arguments directly into a function call. First we make a class that can deserialize any POD type (could probably be relaxed to trivially copyable) from a `char*`:

```
struct deserializer {
  const std::uint8_t* in_;

  deserializer(const std::uint8_t* in) : in_{in} {}

  template <typename T>
  operator T() {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>(), "");
    T t;
    std::memcpy(&t, in_, sizeof(T));
    in_ += sizeof(T);
    return t;
  }
};
```

and then you can generically implement `unpack` as:

```
template <typename...Ts, typename F>
void unpack(F&& f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  deserializer d{from};
  std::forward<F>(f)(static_cast<Ts>(d)...); // Oops, broken.
}
```

Except that it has unspecified behavior, due to the fact that the order of function arguments is unspecified. Let's introduce a type to forward the parameters to the function, so that we can use brace initialization to force left-to-right evaluation:

```
struct forwarder {
  template <typename F, typename...Ts>
  forwarder(F&& f, Ts&&...ts) {
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

// Requires explicit specification of argument types.
template <typename...Ts, typename F>
void unpack(F&& f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  deserializer d{from};
  forwarder{std::forward<F>(f), static_cast<Ts>(d)...};
}
```

and throw in a couple of specializations to deduce argument types from function pointers and `std::function` so we don't always have to specify them:

```
// Deduce argument types from std::function
template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(std::function<R(Args...)> f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack<Args...>(std::move(f), from);
}

// Deduce argument types from function pointer
template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(R (*f)(Args...), const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack<Args...>(f, from);
}
```

It's all nicely exposed to the compiler and very optimizable. Change in binary size between single and double-call versions is minimal ([stealing T.C.'s framework](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be128b1f97a3c681)):

Using function pointers: ~2K at -O0, 64B at -O3.

Using `std::function`: ~3K at -O0, 216B at -O3.

The code to unpack and call is a couple of dozen assembly instructions. E.g.,
with gcc 4.9.2 on x64 optimizing for size with `-Os`, the explicit specialization

```
template void unpack(decltype(foo1), const std::uint8_t*);
```

[assembles to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c73a7025535c337):

```
pushq   %rax
movq    %rsi, %rax
movswl  4(%rsi), %ecx
movzwl  2(%rsi), %edx
movq    %rdi, %r10
movsbl  1(%rsi), %esi
movzbl  (%rax), %edi
pushq   22(%rax)
pushq   14(%rax)
movl    10(%rax), %r9d
movl    6(%rax), %r8d
movsd   34(%rax), %xmm1
movss   30(%rax), %xmm0
call    *(%r10)
addq    $24, %rsp
ret
```

The code size is small enough to be inlined effectively, so the number of templates generated isn't a factor.

### EDIT: Generalizing to non-PODs.

Wrapping up the input iterator in `deserializer` and using a conversion operator to perform the actual unpacking is "clever" - using both the positive and the negative connotations of "clever" - but it's not extensible. Client code can't add `operator blahblah` member function overloads, and the only way to control overloading for conversion operators is with heaps of SFINAE. Yuck. So let's give up the `deserializer` idea, and use an extensible dispatch mechanism.

First, a metafunction to strip references and cv-qualifiers so that we can e.g. unpack `std::vector<double>` when a parameter signature is `const std::vector<double>&`:

```
template <typename T>
using uncvref =
  typename std::remove_cv<
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
  >::type;
```

I'm a fan of tag dispatching, so devise a tag wrapper that can hold any type:

```
template <typename T> struct arg_tag {};
```

and then we can have a generic argument unpack function that performs the tag dispatch:

```
template <typename T>
uncvref<T> unpack_arg(const std::uint8_t*& from) {
  return unpack_arg(arg_tag<uncvref<T>>{}, from);
```

Thanks to the magic of Argument Dependent Lookup, overloads of `unpack_arg` declared *after* the definition of the dispatcher will be found as long as they are declared before use. I.e., the dispatch system is easily extensible. We'll provide the POD unpacker:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivial<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
T unpack_arg(arg_tag<T>, const std::uint8_t*& from) {
  T t;
  std::memcpy(&t, from, sizeof(T));
  from += sizeof(T);
  return t;
}
```

which technically matches *any* `arg_tag`, but is removed from overload resolution by SFINAE if the matched type is non-trivial. (Yes, I know I said POD before. I changed my mind; trivial types are a little more general and still `memcpy`-able.) The front end to this dispatch mechanism doesn't change much:

```
struct forwarder {
  template <typename F, typename...Args>
  forwarder(F&& f, Args&&...args) {
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

// Requires explicit specification of argument types.
template <typename...Ts, typename F>
void unpack(F&& f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  forwarder{std::forward<F>(f), unpack_arg<Ts>(from)...};
}
```

`forwarder` is unchanged, the `unpack<Types...>()` API uses `unpack_arg<Ts>(from)...` in place of `static_cast<Ts>(d)...` but obviously still has the same structure. The type-deducing overloads:

```
template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(std::function<R(Args...)> f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack<Args...>(std::move(f), from);
}

template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(R (*f)(Args...), const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack<Args...>(f, from);
}
```

Work correctly unchanged. Now we can provide an extension to unpack vectors by overloading `unpack_arg` for `arg_tag<std::vector<T>>`:

```
using vec_size_t = int;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> unpack_arg(arg_tag<std::vector<T>>, const std::uint8_t*& from) {
  std::vector<T> vec;
  auto n = unpack_arg<vec_size_t>(from);
  vec.reserve(n);
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), n, [&from]{
    return unpack_arg<T>(from);
  });
  return vec;
}
```

Note how the vector unpack overload goes through the dispatcher to unpack its components: `unpack_arg<vec_size_t>(from)` for the size, and `unpack_arg<T>(from)` for each of the elements.

### Edit again: `std::function<void()>`

Now the code has a problem: if `f` is `std::function<void()>` or `void(*)(void)` then the `unpack` overloads that deduce argument types from `f` will call themselves and recurse infinitely. The easiest fix is to name the function that does the actual work of unpacking something different - I'll pick `unpack_explicit` - and have the various `unpack` frontends call it:

```
template <typename...Ts, typename F>
void unpack_explicit(F&& f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  forwarder{std::forward<F>(f), unpack_arg<Ts>(from)...};
}

// Requires explicit specification of argument types.
template <typename...Ts, typename F>
void unpack(F&& f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack_explicit<Ts...>(std::forward<F>(f), from);
}

// Deduce argument types from std::function
template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(std::function<R(Args...)> f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack_explicit<Args...>(std::move(f), from);
}

// Deduce argument types from function pointer
template <typename R, typename...Args>
void unpack(R (*f)(Args...), const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack_explicit<Args...>(f, from);
}
```

[Here it is all put together.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d0d054a27698c7b) If you prefer to get a compile error for functions with return types other than `void`, drop the `R` parameter that deduces the return type from the deducing overloads and simply use `void`:

```
// Deduce argument types from std::function
template <typename...Args>
void unpack(std::function<void(Args...)> f, const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack_explicit<Args...>(std::move(f), from);
}

// Deduce argument types from function pointer
template <typename...Args>
void unpack(void (*f)(Args...), const std::uint8_t* from) {
  unpack_explicit<Args...>(f, from);
}
```

Comment: "There's no difference in binary size at all between single and double-call versions, whether those calls are to functions (foo1 and foo2) or std::functions." - I see a [~1KiB difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b372197dabe16379) at `-O3`. I did consider this approach, but decided that using `{}` to force left-to-right evaluation in this instance is probably too subtle.

Comment: @T.C. Using mingw-64 on 64-bit windows, I get exactly the same binary size. Presumably windows executable formats have some alignment requirements that swallowed the difference in the size of the generated code. I unashamedly stole your Coliru command line, so there are now more reasonable numbers.

Comment: Indeed, I see no big difference size-wise between [your approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26f1d13c1fb87450) and [mine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe1fc628affc532f). The numbers in my question included the additional `std::function` since it's part of the code commented out in the OP.

Comment: I found it interesting how your example from [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be128b1f97a3c681) prints out `@; $; 16181; -17810; 1925660945; -106037248; 524288; 458752; 5.51013e-40; 6.95344e-309` on [gcc 4.8.3](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php). Doesn't errors and fails the build or anything, just gives an incorrect result silently, which is quite undesired. Probably either gcc's bug or incomplete C++11 support, [though I throughout C++11 was fully implemented in gcc 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html). But it works fine on gcc 4.9.2 here.

Comment: What is `operator T()` exactly?

Comment: Oh, it's a cast operator. That was new. Moreover, it's an implicit cast, and since it's a template -- it can be cast to pretty much anything, and because of that T will be forced to be exactly the type the function accepts. That's clever.

Comment: @Casey what about overloading for non-PODs? @T.C. said that it's better to use your code if I want to handle `std::vector<T>`, but you stated that your code doesn't work with non-PODs easily...

Comment: @FlyingHat Added to the answer with a reworked extensible dispatch mechanism.

Comment: Trivially copyable should be sufficient.

Comment: Just to generalize, I wonder if it also works with `unpack(std::function<void()>(foo), buff);`, i.e. function with no arguments. I'd expect unpack do nothing in that case. I think I could just overload `unpack_arg` for `arg_tag<void>`, which would be triggered in the case the function accepts no arguments, i.e. `T={}`. Will have to test that.

Comment: Made it work with functions accepting nothing by requiring `unpack` overloads to have at least 1 argument in `Args` variadic template type and additionally overloading it without that requirement, in which case I just call the function directly. [here is the modification](http://pastebin.com/YirvKFuh). You might say that it's silly to do so with a function accepting no arguments, I shouldn't be calling `unpack` in such case at all, since there is nothing to deserialize into, but I have a valid use case for this.

Comment: I wonder why in your ["Here it is all put together"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56bedcf79dbfb41c) you made `unpack` overloads return `R`, even though they return a value from a call to `unpack` that returns only `void`. That breaks compilation if we use those overloads for any function that returns things other than `void`, yet you give a promise to return `R`. Kind of makes a sense instead of overloading `unpack` that way to make separate functions with `R` being `void`, i.e. accepting only 1 template type, which is a list of function argument types.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of declaring `template void unpack(decltype(foo1), const std::uint8_t*);` at the very last line?

Comment: Bah - I was trying different things to get the return value of the function out of `unpack`, none with much success. I inadvertently left the `R` in there. That last line is an explicit template specialization to force the compiler to emit a non-inlined version of `unpack(decltype(foo1), ...)` so I could examine the assembly emitted when the compiler can't optimize based on knowledge of the actual parameters. It's not significant to the program itself. I'll get that code cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

First, a function to perform the actual unpacking. Specialize as needed.

```
template<class T>
T do_unpack(uint8_t * data){
    T val;
    memcpy(&val, data, sizeof(T));
    return val;
}
```

Next, a recursive template to compute the offset of the `I`-th element. This can be written as an iterative C++14 `constexpr` function as well, but GCC 4.9 doesn't support that, and doesn't seem to optimize the non-`constexpr` version well. And a C++11 `return`-only recursive `constexpr` doesn't feel like it's worth the trouble over the traditional approach.

```
// compute the offset of the I-th element
template<size_t I, class T, class... Ts>
struct get_offset_temp {
    static constexpr size_t value = get_offset_temp<I-1, Ts...>::value + sizeof(T);
};

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct get_offset_temp<0, T, Ts...>{
    static constexpr size_t value = 0;
};
```

Now, a function to retrieve the `I`-th argument, using the computed offset:

```
template<size_t I, class... Ts>
std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>> unpack_arg(uint8_t *data){
     using T = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
     return do_unpack<T>(data + get_offset_temp<I, Ts...>::value);
}
```

And finally, the function that unpacks the argument and calls the `function`. To avoid a needless copy of `f` I passed it by reference:

```
template<class... Ts, size_t... Is>
void unpack(const std::function<void(Ts...)> &f, uint8_t *dataOffset, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    f(unpack_arg<Is, Ts...>(dataOffset)...);
}
```

And the actual function you call, which merely constructs a compile-time integer sequence and calls the function above:

```
template<class... Ts>
void unpack(std::function<void(Ts...)> f, uint8_t *dataOffset){
    return unpack(f, dataOffset, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/787fbc82206c5d9f).

The difference in binary size between one and two calls is ~1KiB at `-O3`, and [~8 KiB at `-O0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad7c934ce616d336).

`index_sequence` and friends are C++14 features, but implementable in C++11. There are plenty of implementations on SO. For C++11, also replace `tuple_element_t<...>` with `typename tuple_element<...>::type`.

Comment: Your choice to use a separate function for `do_unpack` is definitely superior to mine, since it's possible to overload it to deserialize non-PODs without changing the rest of the machinery.

Comment: It seems sensible to me define both function objects in the 1-call *and* 2-call tests. We want to measure the size of the code generated by the unpacking, not all the additional template goo added by `std::function` and it's type-erasure machinery. Making that change, [your deltas are 5K at -O0 and 216 bytes at -O3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07608cbce574c490). It would appear both our answers have similar code size efficiency.

Comment: @Casey Indeed; I just followed the code in the OP (which commented out the second function object) to make my numbers directly comparable to theirs.

Comment: A quite nice `integer_sequence` implementation can be found [here](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/source/24293c100405bf3982732f53897b4beb962a9086:integer_seq.h).

Comment: @FlyingHat That's actually a rather naive implementation. There are more sophisticated ones on SO that are easier on compilers (`log N` instantiations instead of `N`)

Comment: How can I specialize `get_offset_temp` for `T=float`? Want to use a constant/define instead of `sizeof(T)` for `float`.

Comment: @FlyingHat So instead of `sizeof(T)` do `template<class T> struct size_of : std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof(T)> {};` and use `size_of<T>::value`, then specializing `size_of<float>` is straightforward.

Comment: That's what I like about the original code in the question -- it memcpys and advances the `data` pointer in a single function which can be overloaded for new types. It's nice because I can, say, memcpy `N` of doubles into the buffer and memcpy that `N` right before they start in the buffer. Then I could make a function accepting `std::vector` right at the point where `N` is. I can overload the unpack function for `std::vector`, read `N`, read N next doubles and advance the `data` pointer by `N*sizeof(double)`.

Comment: i.e. the buffer in `main` is filled like [blah, blah, blah, int N = 3, double, double, double, blah] and the function signature that gets called at the end is `void foo(blah, blah, blah, std::vector<double>, blah)`. Then there is an overload for unpack that accepts `std::vector<double>`, which knows that it should look for an `int` N at the current position and then read N next doubles, stacking them into a `std::vector<double>`. That's only possible because I can advance the `data` pointer in the same unpack function.

Comment: @FlyingHat In that case, use Casey's approach.